# Parallel Operation Problems

Tags: generator, power-engineering

How do I set up a [Woodward 2301A](http://www.woodward.com/AnalogEGD2301A.aspx) load sharing device when operating generators in parallel?

Currently, when running two generators in parallel, the first generator takes too much load, and the second generator trips on reverse-power protection.

PS: We used SPM-A for synchronizer

---

**Woodward 2301A Speed Control**

- The Woodward 2301A Speed Control controls the speed or load of diesel or gas engines, or steam or gas turbines.
- The unit provides control in the isochronous mode, with droop available through an externally wired
  potentiometer. The isochronous mode is used for constant speed of the controlled prime mover as long as it is able to provide power to satisfy the load.
- The -  2301A Speed Control is compatible with Woodward SPM-A synchronizers, load sensors, and other power generation controls. These controls can be added to the system at any time, using the auxiliary or SPM inputs to the 2301A Speed Control. The 2301A Speed Control is available for forward- or reverse-acting applications, and can be used with single or tandem actuators. High voltage models accept 88 to 132 Vac or 90 to 150 Vdc, and low voltage models accept 10 to 40 Vdc supply for control power.

Comment: What are you trying to control the speed of? Why do you think we know - you do not tell us ANYWHERE. The 1201A can control diesel engines or petrol engines or steam turbines or gas turbines and quite possibly also wind turbines and Pelton wheels and more. | When what is in parallel with what - how would we know? What takes over the load to high? - how would we know? Reverse power from where to where when what? - how would we know. || There is a good question lurking in there but it is very very very well hidden. You MUST tell us in detail what you are trying to do or your question is useless.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.  This mess of a question needs to be closed.

Comment: See "question" - comment field is not adequate.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to tell what is being asked here. What is needed is specific detail. Two devices are intended to be used in a load sharing arrangement. The 2301A load sharing controller is meant to enforce sharing. Failure to work suggests that the voltage does not droop enough to allow the voltage to fall below that of the second energy source before the load gets too large and trips the overload protection.

The 2301A is a device which allows load sharing between two power generation systems. It creates a sagging load/voltage relationship so that as an alternator etc is loaded it drops below local bus voltage and causes a more lightly loaded and thus higher voltage generator to pick up progressively more load.

Assuming that the equipment is not faulty it seems likely that voltage shaping being applied to one machine is not adequate to drop the voltage enough for the second alternator to load share. The 2301A can have the amount of "droop" under load adjusted with a pot. I'd guess that the pot needs to be adjusted so that the voltage droops more under load than at present.

---

Recall the old "joke"  - What do you call a person who speaks 3 languages / 2 lanhuagrses / one language.
A: Trilingual / Bilingual. guar An Ame....
It's not funny, alas.

This question is worth persevering with for at least 2 excellent reasons.

1. It is a classic "English as a second language" situation where the OP writes far too little, as expressing the question cogently in English is difficult.
   AND some English only speakers who are bright technically are not able to get their brain around the language constructs.

   The OP's problem is clear - they have adequately explained what they want to do and the equipment used and what is going wrong.
   What is required is clear. The details are not.

   A small amount of persuasion will fill in the gaps.

   (2) This is a vastly more rewarding question than about 90% that get asked here. This is a real world application of a complex and unusual piece of equipment doing a crucial real world task.  Having this topic discussed here will be the first introduction that many people have to this piece of equipment.